# Display PDF Files in Visual Studio one after another

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2012

The Visual Studio C# application I am trying to develop will perform the following function:
1. Browse For a Directory 
2. Read One PDF by PDF File and Save the details to .csv or .xlsx file or any database. **[Need Help Here, Reading One File After Another and Display in the Panel on LHS]**

Image Link for the App i'd need your help with. [Image Link - Screenshot of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVI5j.png)

This is the Code Snippet for Reading the pdf file and viewing it.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileD = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK){
            axAcroPDF1.src = openFileD.Filename;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Thomas I tried Adobe PDF Reader using COM components to display a single file. It's working. Need help with cascading files. Reading one file from directory after another.

Comment: Show us your code, it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: @Thomas Added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pick a directory you'd need a **FolderBrowserDialog**. You can store the file list in a member field and the index of the file being displayed so you can find the next one:

```
private FileInfo[] pdfFiles;
private int currentFileIndex = 0;
```

Then in the Browse Directory button click handler display the directory picker and save the list of PDF files and display the first one:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    DirectoryInfo selectedDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(dialog.SelectedPath);
    pdfFiles = selectedDirectory.GetFiles("*.pdf");

    DisplayFileInfo(currentFileIndex);
}
```

In the Save and Nex File click handler, save the file info and get the next file using the index:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save to file

    currentFileIndex++;

    DisplayFileInfo(currentFileIndex);
}
```

and the bit that shows the PDF:

```
private void DisplayFileInfo(int index)
{
    var currentFile = pdfFiles[index];
    axAcroPDF1.src = currentFile.FullName;

    // more assignments
}
```

Please note this is not a fully working example. I haven't compiled and tested the code but should work with minor fixes if any required.

Hope this helps.